# multilanguage title in fragmentpageradapter

Tags: title, multilingual, fragmentpageradapter

I'm working with a FragmentPagerAdapter and I want to set the Title-information ("News, Information, Help, Memebership" - see code below) in different languages. The question is how can I read the titles from res/values/strings.xml?

Does someone could help me?

Thanks

Tom

```
public class MainInfoViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements    PageIndicator
{
private String[] titles= new String[]
        {          
        "News",          
        "Information",         
        "Help",
        "Membership"
        };   
public MainInfoViewPagerAdapter( FragmentManager fm) 
{
    super(fm);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it:

In the adapter:

```
public class TitleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String titles[];
    private Fragment frags[];

    public TitleAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
                super(fm);

                Resources resources = context.getResources();
                titles = resources.getStringArray(R.array.titles);

                frags = new Fragment[titles.length]; 

                frags[0] = new NewsFragment();
                frags[1] = new ArtistsFragment();
                frags[2] = new InfoFragment();
                frags[3] = new EatDrinkFragment();

         ....
```

/values/arrays.xml Looks like this:

```
<string-array name="titles">
        <item>NEWS</item>
        <item>ARTISTS</item>
        <item>INFORMATION</item>
        <item>EAT AND DRiNK</item>
    </string-array>
```

If you want to an language, just add another values-folder like /values-fr/strings.xml for french for example.

Answer (score 0):

I manage it creating an private `SparseArray<String> TITLES;` and fill it on the OnCreate function in the main Activity, something like this:

```
   TITLES = new SparseArray<String>();
    TITLES.put(KEY_FRAGMENT,
            getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_keys));
    TITLES.put(CERTIFICATE_FRAGMENT,
            getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_cert));
    TITLES.put(TRUST_NETWORK_FRAGMENT,
            getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_trust_network));
    TITLES.put(CRL_FRAGMENT, getResources()
            .getString(R.string.subtitle_crl));
    TITLES.put(SECURE_FRAGMENT,
            getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_secure));
    TITLES.put(SETTINGS_FRAGMENT,
            getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_settings));
```

And finaly in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` in `getTitle` do something like this:

```
  @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            // Fragment of the app is the Key Management.
            return TITLES.get(position);
        case 1:
            // Fragment of the app is the Certificate Management.
            return TITLES.get(position);

        case 2:
            // Fragment of the app is the Trust Network Management.
            return TITLES.get(position);

        case 3:
            // Fragment of the app is the CRL Management.
            return TITLES.get(position);

        default:
            return TITLES.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Maybe its not the best way, but its a way!

Comment: Hi Javier, "TITLES cannot be resolved" in FragmentPagerAdapter in getTitle(). What can I do? Best regards Tom

Comment: Do you create FragmentPagerAdapter as inner class for the main Activity class rigth?? If you do, just declare TITLES as attribute for the main class, so the inner class can have access to it. This is one aproach, but i'll post an other aproach that i have tested for my app.

Answer (score 0):

The other aproach that you can test is this. For this test i have created an activity with tabs, and each time the user select a tab, the subtitle in the action bar is changed using to diferent languages (English/Spanish). So Im guessing that your Activity structure is something like this:

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
- In this class you have one ViewPager and one PagerAdapter as attributes
- PagerAdapter is a inner class inside MainActivity.
```

the code is something like this, First the main activity:

```
 public class TrustNetworkActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
private SparseArray<String> TITLES;
ViewPager mViewPager;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DataBaseDictionary.PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName();
        //Loads the data base
        initDBLoader(this);
        fillSubtitlesArray();
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections
        // of the app.
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        // ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        ab.setSubtitle(TITLES.get(KEY_FRAGMENT));
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener
        // for when the user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        // When swiping between different app sections, select
                        // the corresponding tab.
                        // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if
                        // we have a reference to the
                        // Tab.
                        ab.setSubtitle(TITLES.get(position));
                        ab.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_keys)
                .setTabListener(this));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_cert)
                .setTabListener(this));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_trust_network).setTabListener(this));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_crl)
                .setTabListener(this));
ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}

/**
     * Fills the subtitle array with the resource strings, so it would be
     * multilanguage
     */
    private void fillSubtitlesArray() {
        TITLES = new SparseArray<String>();
        TITLES.put(0,
                getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_keys));
        TITLES.put(1,
                getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_cert));
        TITLES.put(2,
                getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_trust_network));
        TITLES.put(3, getResources()
                .getString(R.string.subtitle_crl));
        TITLES.put(4,
                getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_secure));
        TITLES.put(5,
                getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle_settings));

    }
```

As you can see in the `OnPageChangeListener` on the ViewPager, i have called the action bar `setSubtitle` method so, each time the user select a new page, the subtitle of my action bar is changed, Then the adapter:

```
   /**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the primary sections of the app.
 */
public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            // Fragment of the app
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            // Fragment of the app
            return new Fragment2();

        case 2:
            // Fragment of the app
            return new Fragment3();

        case 3:
            // Fragment of the app
            return new Fragment4();

        default:
            return new Fragment5();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you!